# Why `dev.size()` and actual size of on-screen device are different?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, device

Problem (what you see is not quite what you get): I want to save exactly the same ggplot that appears on my screen to .png file, i.e. with the same width and height in order to maintain the same font size as on screen.

`ggsave()` function uses `dev.size()` values as default for `width` and `height`. In principle, it must ensure that `width` and `height` on screen and in the file are the same. But they are not (font sizes are clearly different, as well as sizes of lines etc.).

I was curious if it is the same story with RStudio GUI of saving plots, and in fact, they are different. See picture below:

[image: screenshot from RStudio console showing output of dev.size() as 8.777778 4.430556 and the size in "Save Plot as PDF" dialogue as 6.58 x 3.32 inches]

**Example:**

Method #1:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, qsec))
print(p)
ggsave(filename = "a/path/to/file.png", plot = p)
```

Method #2:

Plots -> Export -> Save as PDF...

Comment: I think you need to add a little more info.  Can you show a simple example of the plotting code you use that leads to the size difference in the dev.size of the RStudio window and the dev.size returned by `dev.size()`?  I can't currently reproduce this RStudio 1.1.453/R 3.4.4.  I can make it happen if I open a new device via `dev.new()` but that may not be relevant.

Comment: @aosmith I have updated the question

Comment: I can't reproduce.  When I make your example plot and save it (in a clean session), `ggsave()` tells me `Saving 6.67 x 3.66 in image`.  When I go to Save as PDF and choose PDF Size as "(Device size)" the dimensions match those.

Comment: @aosmith I am using macOS 10.13.3, R 3.4.3, RStudio 1.1.423, and ggplot2 2.2.1. I will update everything and try to reproduce the example. If it happens again, I will simply post in RStudio support (I believe this is RStudio IDE issue).